# gl_FragCoord with ivec2 conversion

Tags: c++, opengl

**Question**:
Will the function **ivec2** do a remap from 0...1 to (e.g.) 0...1024 ?

**Details:**

In the OpenGL Superbible book there is code:

```
color = texelFetch(s, ivec2(gl_FragCoord.xy), 0);
```

**glFragCoord** “This variable is an input to the fragment shader that holds the **floating-point coordinate** of the fragment being processed in window coordinates. However, the texelFetch function accepts integer-point coordinates that range **from (0, 0)** to the **width and height** of the texture.”

“Therefore, we construct a two-component integer vector (ivec2) from the x and y components of gl_FragCoord."

Answer (score 1):

No; how will it know what range you want remap to?

`gl_FragCoord` is floating point, but it isn't in `[0; 1]` range.

Comment: Yes, but when gl_FragCoord is floating point and texelFetch accepts integer-point how can it work together?

Comment: You already did conversion to integer with `ivec2` cast. What's problem with that?